# Removing an sqlite db in Android

Tags: android

I'm debugging my android app in Android Studio using a real android device and. I see that the Sqlite db path is

```
/data/data/com.my_app/databases/data1.db
```

I want to remove it. By that path doesn't exist when try to find it by a file manager. And, of course, this isn't working:

```
adb -e shell rm /data/data/com.my_app/databases/data1.db
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
error: device not found
```

So how can I remove it and why isn't it visible in my smartphone?

Comment: It's not visible on your smartphone because you don't have root access, by default. To remove it, simply uninstall your app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why isn't it visible in my smartphone?

Because it is on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), which you do not have access to, except on emulators and rooted devices.

> And, of course, this isn't working:

That is some separate problem with `adb` running on your machine.

> So how can I remove it

If you want to completely clear your app's data (databases, `SharedPreferences`, and other files) on internal storage, use the Settings (e.g., Settings > Apps > (your app) > Clear Data on Android 4.x/5.x).

If you specifically want to get rid of this file on an emulator, the command you tried should be fine. I suggest restarting the emulator.

If you specifically want to get rid of this file on production hardware, you will need to use `run-as`:

```
adb shell run-as com.my_app rm /data/data/com.my_app/databases/data1.db
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't reach that directory if your device isn't **root** . For change or modify system files you must have root access .